# logging javascript module names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to log my module initializations to see what happens. Is there a way to get the module namespace and log it to the console.

```
(function($, bis, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    //other app code
    bis.library = bis.library || function(module) {
        $(function() {
            if (module.init) {
                module.init();
                //how can I make it log the module namespace
                console.log('module' + module.toString() + 'initialized');
            }
        });
        return module;
    };

    //other app code
})(jQuery, window._bis = window._bis || {}, window, document);
```

example of my module definition

```
(function($, bis, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    var common = bis.common,
        urls = bis.urls,
        defaults = bis.defaults,
        createWorklist = bis.createWorklist,
        editWorklist = bis.editWorklist,
        editMoveBoxesWorklist = bis.editMoveBoxesWorklist;

    bis.worklist = bis.worklist || bis.library((function() {
        // module variables
        var init = function() {
            //module init code
        };

        //other module code

        return {
            init: init
        };
    })());
})(jQuery, window._bis = window._bis || {}, window, document);​
```

So I want the line console.log to log the following text "module bis.worklist initialized" for example.

Comment: You cannot do that, as there is no name associated with the module wrapper function. What you can do of course is extend your API so that the module can explicitly pass in an identifying string.

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is because my debugger knows the namespace when hovering the init method during debugging, so thats why I think it should be possible somehow.

Comment: The debugger is able to use the source to perform static analysis. That sort of information is just not available to the JavaScript code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as Pointy suggested. I have added a name property to my modules and just use the

```
console.log(module.name);
```